# use $lookup string and objectId in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

how to $lookup strings and $Objcectid in mongoDB version 3.6.
if in version 4.0 there is $toObjectId, is there something like that in version 3.6?

Answer (score 0):

`{ $toObjectId: <expression> }` to `{ $convert: { input: <expression>, to: "objectId" } }`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.